# Explain how pandas DataFrame join works

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Why does inner join work so strange in pandas?

**For example:**

```
import pandas as pd
import io

t1 = ('key,col1\n'
      '1,a\n'
      '2,b\n'
      '3,c\n'
      '4,d')

t2 = ('key,col2\n'
      '1,e\n'
      '2,f\n'
      '3,g\n'
      '4,h')


df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t1), header=0)
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t2), header=0)

print(df1)
print()
print(df2)
print()
print(df2.join(df1, on='key', how='inner', lsuffix='_l'))
```

**Outputs:**

```
   key col1
0    1    a
1    2    b
2    3    c
3    4    d

   key col2
0    1    e
1    2    f
2    3    g
3    4    h

   key_l col2  key col1
0      1    e    2    b
1      2    f    3    c
2      3    g    4    d
```

If I don't specify `lsuffix`, it says

```
ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['key'], dtype='object')
```

Does this function work differently from SQL's JOIN? Why does it want to create an extra 'key' column with a suffix? Why are there only 3 rows?
I expected it to output something like this:

```
   key col1 col2
0    1    a    e
1    2    b    f
2    3    c    g
3    4    d    h
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first:
What you wanted was merge

```
df1.merge(df2)
```

[image]

---

`join` defaults to merging on the `index`.  You can specify the `on` parameter which only says which column from left side to match with the index of the right side.

These might help illustrate

```
df1.set_index('key').join(df2.set_index('key'))
```

[image]

```
df1.join(df2.set_index('key'), on='key')
```

[image]

---

Your example is matching the index of `df2` which looks like `[0, 1, 2, 3]` with the `key` column of `df1` which looks like `[1, 2, 3, 4]`
That's why you get `NaN` in `col2` when `key_l` is `4`

```
df1.join(df2, on='key', lsuffix='_l', how='outer')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. What does join do then?

Comment: @spiderface was working on more comprehensive answer.  post has been updated.